# INSERT ... SELECT ON DUPLICATE KEY: Has an insert been made or an update?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, sql-update

In a SQL query I use the (MySQL database)

```
INSERT ... UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY
```

statement in order to insert or update.

I would like to know if an insert has been made or an update.

I use mysql_insert_id() but the problem I am having is that it does return the row id whether I am inserting or updating.

Comment: This is documented in [the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) docs. Check `mysql_affected_rows()` which should report 1 for an insert and 2 for an update.